# Are questions about programming-related software on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions regarding (programming-related) software? Software like Visual Studio Code, etc.

Example:

> Does FileHistory in VScode store after leaving the program or when does it save a backup?

[Here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: It depends. Questions about tools primarily used by programmers (such as IDEs including VSC) are explicitly *on-topic* here (on main - no programming question is on-topic on Meta). However, this is where things get tricky: the question also needs to be asked in a programming *context* (which, thankfully, is not that hard to do). A question about file history in VSC in your example looks on-topic at first glance, at least to me. It *might* be better-suited on SuperUser, but take this advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: Perhaps find a better example? The current one looks like one that has already been asked. All basic / beginner questions have already been asked on Stack Overflow. It is just a matter of finding them among the [existing 22,687,648 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) (and [50,838 Visual Studio Code questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your question's about an IDE, then it's on-topic (here on Stack Overflow, not Meta Stack Overflow).

People may not particularly *like* the question or think that the question is all that useful, but a question that reads like it's about when the autosave feature in VS Code fires off is on-topic to me.

[I mean, there's *already* a pretty good question about it with comprehensive answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181761/auto-saving-files-upon-changes-with-vscode).

<sup>So if you were to ask something similar to the linked question, it *would* get closed as a dupe.  Something to keep in mind.</sup>